# SQL Standard for function arguments

Tags: sql, standards

Is there a SQL standard for specifying function arguments as password type?

For example, if I write a SQL function, which can be called like:

```
my_func('host', 'port', 'user', 'pwd')
```

Is there a way for me to specify during function definition that the fourth argument is a password?

**Edit**: I am looking for either a data type or some attribute that can be used to indicate that the field is a password type field.

Comment: Which DBMS?  The standard will be largely irrelevant in this area.  What's the system going to do if it knows that the fourth parameter is a password?

Comment: I _think_ the standard defines `:=` for passing named parameters: `my_func(p_hostname := 'host', p_port := 'port', p_password := 'pwd')` but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: ANSI SQL defines <named argument assignment token> as =>.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Say, it'll mask it in DB logs.

Comment: Hiding the value from logging makes some sense.  You'll need to look in the manuals of your system, but I'd be surprised if there was such a facility.  Pleasantly surprised.  Of itself, it isn't a bad idea, but it would be better handled by an attribute on the parameter ('unlogged' or something) than simply based on the argument name.